# Component in Angular 8 with Ivy does not render

Tags: angular-components, angular-ivy

I have been sifting through various articles over the last couple of hours and I cannot figure out why Angular 8 with Ivy is throwing me a curveball.

Consider the following directory:

[image]

Media-library will be a component I would like to render on the Dashboard.

In Angular 7 without the Ivy engine, this would have been a simple task to complete, however, I cannot get this to work with Ivy.

In media-library.module.ts I have (code removed for brevity):

```
declarations: [MediaLibraryComponent],
entryComponents: [MediaLibraryComponent],
exports: [MediaLibraryComponent] /* add this because i tried everything */
```

Then in the app.module.ts, I imported this module (code removed for brevity):

```
imports: [MediaLibraryModule]
```

Adding  to app.component.html renders this just fine, as I added the import of the module to app.module.ts, working on the assumption that Angular 8 Ivy still sees global imports, I thought that if I moved the HTML block to dashboard.component.html, it would still work? Not a chance.

I then removed it from app.module.ts and added it to dashboard.module.ts hoping that importing the module where I actually need it would work? Not a chance.

I even added the MediaLibraryComponent as a declaration directly to dashboard.module.ts hoping it would pick it up. Still nothing.

I'm dead certain this is something to with Ivy, I just don't know what? I've read through the documentation looking for any breaking changes that might affect entryComponents, however, everything I have now, is still valid.

Has anyone else run into this and now how to fix it?

Comment: Hey man, have you figured out how to fix it?

Comment: @antonyboom, yeah, entryComponents: [MediaLibraryComponent], are no longer required in Angular 8 (Ivy)+. also, you need to make sure that you understand your needs.